# pyspark filter columns values based on a list of list values

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I wish to filter the values for multiple columns based on a list of values.

For example, I have a list of values as below:

```
list_example= [[10,"test", 100],
[20, "test2", 50],
[30, "test5", 100],
[40, "test6", 200],
..]
```

My dataframe in pyspark is as following: the following is example, it should be a lot.

```
data = {"Value": [10,50,70,80, 88, 99, 40],
       "String": ["test", "other", "string", "are", "in", "test", "test6"],
       "total": [100,100,300,500,600,111, 200]}
```

My current method:

```
for l in list_example:
    df.filter((F.col("Value").isin(l[0]))&(F.col("String").isin(l[1]))&(F.col("total").isin(l[2]))).show()
```

My issue: I dont think the way I loop each list and filter it is correct, too time consuming.

1. My list_example list contained more than thousands list of values. so when I len(list_example) is has more than 2000 lists.
2. My data contained more than millions of data.
3. When I use for i in list_example and then filter it through the data it will be taking so long.

I am wondering whether is there a way to filter the values based on the set of list values and then when matching is found, combine all the found and show it? or save it in another dataframe?

My condition is as below:

```
(value in <val> AND string in <str> AND total in <tot>)

So in order to get the filter row, it will need to satisfied <val>,<str>,<tol>. So using AND is my intention.
```

Comment: how are the filters applied across 2 lists? list1 & list2 & list3 ... ? OR, should it be list1 or list2 or list3 ... ?

Comment: sorry, I dont get what you mean. Could you add a little more details about what you want to confirm.

Comment: Did you mean each list within list_example? Lets say, [10,"test", 100], then I want to filter pyspark dataframe to find a row that have exactly values as [10,"test", 100].

Comment: It should be exactly having [10,"test", 100] without a single missing out.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my examples. Based on the above, it will be able to filter 2 rows, [10,"test", 100] and [40, "test6", 200] because it meet all three same value within the list in pyspark rows.

Comment: so, it's an `OR` condition between lists (of list_example)

Comment: I get what you mean now. Yes, it will be OR condition because I wish to loop each list within list_examples and then match with pyspark rows dataframe and find whether all three values within the list is exactly matched. So if the first list is not match then search the second list in list_example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter condition using `map()` and `reduce()` python functions.

```py
filter_cond = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, 
                     map(lambda x: ((func.col('value') == x[0]) & (func.col('string') == x[1]) & (func.col('total') == x[2])), 
                         ls_for_filter
                         )
                     )

filtered_data_sdf = data_sdf.filter(filter_cond)
```

The `filter_cond` variable can be passed within `filter()`. Using your example below.

```py
data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data_ls))

# +-----+------+-----+
# |Value|String|total|
# +-----+------+-----+
# |   10|  test|  100|
# |   50| other|  100|
# |   70|string|  300|
# |   80|   are|  500|
# |   88|    in|  600|
# |   99|  test|  111|
# |   40| test6|  200|
# +-----+------+-----+

data_sdf. \
    filter(filter_cond). \
    show()

# +-----+------+-----+
# |Value|String|total|
# +-----+------+-----+
# |   10|  test|  100|
# |   40| test6|  200|
# +-----+------+-----+
```